# Vue.js: v-html not working as expected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using `keen-ui` library which is a lightweight `Vue.js` UI library. I am using `ui-select` component from library. I am trying to use `v-html` attribute but it is somehow not working as expected. I have following code inside template:

```
  <template>
  <ui-select
            label="Color"
            placeholder="Color"
            :options="SelectColors"
            v-model="color"
            v-html="red"
        ></ui-select>
 </template>

 <script>
import { UiSelect } from 'keen-ui'
export default {
   data () {
      red: '<div class="foo red"></div>',
      SelectColours: [
    {
      label: this.red,
      value: 'red'
    }]
   },
   components: { UiSelect }
}

<style>
.foo {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
</style>
```

I am expecting it to show select option with only red color box. Any idea why it is not working as I expect?

Comment: You won't be able to use `v-html` on a component, it will just be ignored. I also can't see anything in the [docs](https://josephuspaye.github.io/Keen-UI/#/ui-select) that suggests that you can insert your own markup in the the select box.

Comment: `v-html` is intended to replace the entire contents of the element. Are you trying to use it like a slot?